# How can I optmize my directory file search method?

Tags: c#

I am tasked with looking for files in a network location with many many sub directories. My current implementation is based on answers I found on stackoverflow:

```
private void PollFolder(string sourceDir)
{
    try
    {
        // var start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-_filesToGetTimeRangeFromNowInDays);
        var start = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-5);
        var end = DateTime.Now;

        var filesFromToolDir = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.gz", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => new FileInfo(f).CreationTime >= start 
                            && new FileInfo(f).CreationTime <= end)
                .ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I am supposed to filter files by creation date in a certain time range given by the user. Here I am using an example of 5 months. The issue with this function is that for some directories, it can take up to 5 hours to find files within a specified time range.

**My question**: is there any way for me to optimize and make this file search across a network folder with many sub directories faster? Is there a better way to look for files?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As long as this only needs to work on Windows OS, I'd recommend using the Winapi functions FindFirstFileExW and FindNextFile. This will give you by far the most efficient solution. I can send you some code that does what you want tomorrow. The C# System.IO namespace is rather slow compared to the native Winapi functions. I can query several thousand files in a few milliseconds using the Winapi methods mentioned above.

Comment: @Max yes I think it only runs on Windows OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making more network requests than you need. `Directory.GetFiles()` makes a network request, but only returns a string. Then you're using `new FileInfo(f).CreationTime` twice, but because you're creating a new `FileInfo` object twice, it's making two network requests to get the same information.

You can cut this down by using [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles), which returns `FileInfo` objects rather than just the file name. This way, you're getting the creation time as part of the results.

```
var start = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-5);
var end = DateTime.Now;

var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);
var filesFromToolDir = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.gz", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(f => f.CreationTime >= start 
                    && f.CreationTime <= end)
        .ToArray();
```

Ideally, you want to only ask the server for the information you need, rather than requesting everything and discarding results. Unfortunately, you can't do that here.

---

*This may only be relevant to .NET Core:*

`EnumerateFiles` (both in the `Directory` and `DirectoryInfo` classes), use native Windows [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile) function, which you can see in the [code here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/53c42c933605cf86e5d9019457f839c954aeb5af/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Enumeration/FileSystemEnumerator.Windows.cs#L86), and that function only gives the option to filter by file name.

In fact, the .NET code isn't great here, because it [always passes `null` for the `FileName` parameter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/53c42c933605cf86e5d9019457f839c954aeb5af/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Enumeration/FileSystemEnumerator.Windows.cs#L96). So even if you ask for `*.gz` it still gets every file from the server and filters it locally.

Answer (score 2):

The provided code will only work on Windows!
Do not, and I can't stress this enough, call it on C: directly when setting recurse to true. You will run out of memory.

I tested it on my D: drive which contains 1743 folders and 71921 files.
Getting all folders and subfolders as well as all files created in the past 5 months took 938 milliseconds.

How to use it:

```
FileSearchOptions options = new FileSearchOptions(
    new string[] { "*.*" },
    DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-5),
    DateTime.Now
);
string[] dirs = DirectoryUtil.GetDirectories(root, true);
string[] files = DirectoryUtil.LoadFiles(options, dirs);
```

---

**FileSearchOptions**

```
using System;

namespace Your.Namespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains options for a file search.
    /// </summary>
    public struct FileSearchOptions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Array of file type filters.
        /// <para>Text file example: *.txt</para>
        /// </summary>
        public string[] FileTypes;
        /// <summary>
        /// The minimum creation timestamp of the file.
        /// </summary>
        public Nullable<DateTime> CreationTimeMin;
        /// <summary>
        /// The maximum creation timestamp of the file.
        /// </summary>
        public Nullable<DateTime> CreationTimeMax;
        /// <summary>
        /// The minimum last write timestamp of the file.
        /// </summary>
        public Nullable<DateTime> LastWriteTimeMin;
        /// <summary>
        /// The maximum last write timestamp of the file.
        /// </summary>
        public Nullable<DateTime> LastWriteTimeMax;


        public FileSearchOptions(
            string[] fileTypes,
            DateTime? createdMin = null,
            DateTime? createdMax = null,
            DateTime? lastWriteMin = null,
            DateTime? lastWriteMax = null)
        {
            FileTypes           = fileTypes;
            CreationTimeMin     = createdMin;
            CreationTimeMax     = createdMax;
            LastWriteTimeMin    = lastWriteMin;
            LastWriteTimeMax    = lastWriteMax;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**SystemTime**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace Your.Namespace
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    internal struct SystemTime
    {
        public ushort Year;
        public ushort Month;
        public ushort DayOfWeek;
        public ushort Day;
        public ushort Hour;
        public ushort Minute;
        public ushort Second;
        public ushort Milliseconds;

        public SystemTime(DateTime dt)
        {
            dt = dt.ToUniversalTime();
            Year = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.Year);
            Month = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.Month);
            DayOfWeek = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.DayOfWeek);
            Day = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.Day);
            Hour = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.Hour);
            Minute = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.Minute);
            Second = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.Second);
            Milliseconds = Convert.ToUInt16(dt.Millisecond);
        }

        public SystemTime(ushort year, ushort month, ushort day, ushort hour = 0, ushort minute = 0, ushort second = 0, ushort millisecond = 0)
        {
            Year = year;
            Month = month;
            Day = day;
            Hour = hour;
            Minute = minute;
            Second = second;
            Milliseconds = millisecond;
            DayOfWeek = 0;
        }

        public static implicit operator DateTime(SystemTime st)
        {
            if (st.Year == 0 || st == MinValue)
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            if (st == MaxValue)
                return DateTime.MaxValue;

            //DateTime dt = new DateTime(st.Year, st.Month, st.Day, st.Hour, st.Minute, st.Second, st.Milliseconds, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return new DateTime(st.Year, st.Month, st.Day, st.Hour, st.Minute, st.Second, st.Milliseconds, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(SystemTime s1, SystemTime s2)
        {
            return (s1.Year == s2.Year 
                && s1.Month == s2.Month 
                && s1.Day == s2.Day 
                && s1.Hour == s2.Hour 
                && s1.Minute == s2.Minute 
                && s1.Second == s2.Second 
                && s1.Milliseconds == s2.Milliseconds);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(SystemTime s1, SystemTime s2)
        {
            return !(s1 == s2);
        }

        public static readonly SystemTime MinValue, MaxValue;

        static SystemTime()
        {
            MinValue = new SystemTime(1601, 1, 1);
            MaxValue = new SystemTime(30827, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is SystemTime)
                return ((SystemTime)obj) == this;
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**DirectoryUtil**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ComTypes = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Security;

namespace Your.Namespace
{
    internal static class DirectoryUtil
    {
        //
        // Searches a directory for a file or subdirectory 
        // with a name and attributes that match specified.
        //
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindFirstFileExW(
            string lpFileName,         // The directory or path, and the file name.
            FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS fInfoLevelId,       // The information level of the returned data.
            out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData,     // A pointer to the buffer that receives the file data.
            FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS fSearchOp,          // The type of filtering to perform
                                                  // that is different from wildcard matching.
            IntPtr lpSearchFilter,     // A pointer to the search criteria if the specified fSearchOp 
                                       // needs structured search information.
            int dwAdditionalFlags   // Specifies additional flags that control the search.
        );


        //
        // Continues a file search from a previous call to the 
        // FindFirstFileExW function.
        //
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool FindNextFile(
            IntPtr hFindFile,      // The search handle returned by a previous call
                                   // to the FindFirstFileExW function.
            out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData  // A pointer to the WIN32_FIND_DATA structure
                                                // that receives information about the found file or subdirectory.
        );


        //
        // Converts a file time to system time format.
        // System time is based on UTC.
        //
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool FileTimeToSystemTime(
            [In] ref ComTypes.FILETIME lpFileTIme,     // A pointer to a FILETIME structure containing 
                                                       // the file time to be converted to system UTC.
            out SystemTime lpSystemTime    // A pointer to a SYSTEMTIME structure to
                                           // receive the converted file time.
        );


        //
        // Contains information about the file that is found by
        // the FindFirstFileExW function.
        //
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public FileAttributes dwFileAttributes;     // The file attributes of a file.
            public ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;    // A FILETIME structure taht specifies
                                                        // when a file or directory was created.
            public ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;  // A FILETIME structure that specifies 
                                                        // when the file was last read from, written to, or run (.exe).
            public ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;   // A FILETIME structure that specifies
                                                        // when the files was last written to, trucated, or overwritten.
            public uint nFileSizeHigh;  // The high-order DWORD value of the file size, in bytes.
            public uint nFileSizeLow;   // The low-order DWORD value of the file size, in bytes.
            public uint dwReserved0;    // If the dwFileAttributes member includes the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT
                                        // attribute, this member specifies the reparse point tag.
            public uint dwReserved1;    // Reserved for future use.
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public string cFileName;    // The name of the file.
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
            public string cAlternateFileName;   // An alternative name for the file.
            public uint dwFileType;     // Obsolete. Do not use.
            public uint dwCreatorType;  // Obsolete. Do not use.
            public uint wFinderFlags;   // Obsolete. Do not use.
        }


        // 
        // Defines values that are used with the FindFirstFileEx
        // function to specify the information level of the returned data.
        //
        internal enum FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS
        {
            // The FindFirstFileEx function retrieves a
            // standard set of attribute information. The data is returned in a
            FindExInfoStandard = 0,
            // The FindFirstFileEx function does not query the short file name,
            // improving overall enumeration speed. The data is returned in a
            // WIN32_FIND_DATA structure, and the cAlternateFileName
            // member is always a NULL string.
            // This value is not supported until Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.
            FindExInfoBasic = 1
        }


        //
        // Defines values that are used with the FindFirstFileEx
        // function to specify the type of filtering to perform.
        //
        internal enum FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS
        {
            // The search for a file that matches a specified file name.
            FindExSearchNameMatch = 0,
            // This is an advisory flag.
            // If the file system supports directory filtering, the function
            // searches for a file that matches the specified name and is also a directory.
            // If the file system does not support directory filtering,
            // this flag is silently ignored.
            FindExSearchLimitToDirectories = 1,
            // This filtering type is not available.
            FindExSearchLimitToDevices = 2
        }


        // Searches are case-sensitive. 
        private const int FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE = 1;
        // Uses a larger buffer for directory queries,
        // which can increase performance of the find operation. 
        // This value is not supported until Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.
        private const int FIND_FRIST_EX_LARGE_FETCH = 2;
        // Limits the results to files that are physically on disk.
        // This flag is only relevant when a file virtualization filter is present. 
        private const int FIND_FIRST_EX_ON_DISK_ENTRIES_ONLY = 4;

        // Invalid pointer value.
        private static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);


        // Caught Win32 errors.
        private static List<string> _errors = new List<string>();
        public static string LastError
        {
            get {
                return _errors[_errors.Count - 1];
            }
        }
        public static string[] Errors
        {
            get {
                return _errors.ToArray();
            }
        }


        //
        // Formats a file path to match the search format 
        // of the FindFirstFileExW function.
        //
        private static readonly Func<string, string, string> FormatFilePath = (s, f) =>
        {
            if (s.EndsWith(".") || s.EndsWith("..")) {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            if (s.EndsWith("\\")) {
                s += f;
            }

            if (!(s.EndsWith("\\" + f))) {
                s += "\\" + f;
            }

            if (s == ".\\*" || s == "..\\*") {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return s;
        };


        //
        // Formats a directory path to match the search format 
        // of the FindFirstFileExW function.
        //
        private static readonly Func<string, string> FormatPath = (s) =>
        {
            if (s.EndsWith(".") || s.EndsWith("..")) {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            if (s.EndsWith("\\")) {
                s += "*";
            }

            if (!(s.EndsWith("\\*"))) {
                s += "\\*";
            }

            if (s == ".\\*" || s == "..\\*") {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return s;
        };


        //
        // Gets all files in the specified directory
        // and adds them to the referenced list object.
        //
        private static void LoadFilesInternal(
            string dir, 
            string fileType, 
            FileSearchOptions options, 
            ref List<string> files)
        {
            // Get standard set of information.
            FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS findLevel = FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoStandard;
            // File name search.
            FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS findOps = FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS.FindExSearchNameMatch;

            int additionalFlags = 0;
            // Check if OS version is later supported
            // OS beginning from WinSvr 2008 R2 and Win 7
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
                // Ingore short file name to improve performance.
                findLevel = FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoBasic;
                // Use larger buffer.
                additionalFlags = FIND_FRIST_EX_LARGE_FETCH;
            }

            // Format path to match FindFirstFileExW pattern.
            string search = FormatFilePath(dir, fileType);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)) {
                return;
            }

            WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
            // Try to get handle to first file system object.
            IntPtr hFind = FindFirstFileExW(
                search, findLevel,
                out ffd, findOps,
                IntPtr.Zero, additionalFlags
            );

            // FindFirstFileExW failed...
            if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) {
                int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                _errors.Add("FindFirstFileExW returned Win32 error: " + err);
                return;
            }

            // Stores the end of the path without search pattern.
            // Used to create new file name.
            string end = string.Empty;
            // Stores the new concatinated file name.
            string newDir = string.Empty;
            // SystemTime used to convert WinAPI FILETIME to DateTime.
            SystemTime st;
            // Stores the file creation time.
            DateTime ct;
            // Stores the file last write time.
            DateTime lw;
            // Check if options has a creation time timespan.
            bool hasCreationTime = options.CreationTimeMin.HasValue && options.CreationTimeMax.HasValue;
            // Check if options has a last write time timespan.
            bool hasWriteTime = options.LastWriteTimeMin.HasValue && options.LastWriteTimeMax.HasValue;

            do
            {
                // Ignore if handle points to directory.
                if ((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) 
                    == FileAttributes.Directory)  
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Ignore if handle points to current directory 
                // or top-level directory.
                if (ffd.cFileName == ".." || ffd.cFileName == ".") {
                    continue;
                }

                // Convert FILETIME to SystemTime and 
                // SystemTime to .Net DateTime.
                FileTimeToSystemTime(ref ffd.ftCreationTime, out st);                
                ct = (DateTime)st;
                FileTimeToSystemTime(ref ffd.ftLastWriteTime, out st);
                lw = (DateTime)st;
                
                // No creation time or write is specified.
                if (!(hasCreationTime) && !(hasWriteTime)) {
                    end = search.Replace("\\" + fileType, string.Empty);
                    newDir = end + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ffd.cFileName;
                    files.Add(newDir);
                }
                // Creation time is specified and write time is not.
                else if ((hasCreationTime && !(hasWriteTime)) &&
                    (ct <= options.CreationTimeMax 
                    && ct >= options.CreationTimeMin)) 
                {
                    end = search.Replace("\\" + fileType, string.Empty);
                    newDir = end + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ffd.cFileName;
                    files.Add(newDir);
                }
                // Creation time is not specified and write time is.
                else if ((!(hasCreationTime) && hasWriteTime) &&
                    lw <= options.LastWriteTimeMax 
                    && lw >= options.LastWriteTimeMin) 
                {
                    end = search.Replace("\\" + fileType, string.Empty);
                    newDir = end + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ffd.cFileName;
                    files.Add(newDir);
                }
                // Creation time and write time is specified.
                else if (hasCreationTime && hasWriteTime &&
                    (ct <= options.CreationTimeMax
                    && ct >= options.CreationTimeMin) &&
                    lw <= options.LastWriteTimeMax
                    && lw >= options.LastWriteTimeMin)
                {
                    end = search.Replace("\\" + fileType, string.Empty);
                    newDir = end + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ffd.cFileName;
                    files.Add(newDir);
                }
            } 
            while (FindNextFile(hFind, out ffd));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Loads all files in the referenced directories.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="options">Options for the file search.</param>
        public static string[] LoadFiles(FileSearchOptions options, ICollection<string> directories)
        {
            if (options.FileTypes == null) {
                options.FileTypes = new string[] { "*.*" };
            }

            if (options.FileTypes.Length == 0) {
                options.FileTypes = new string[] { "*.*" };
            }

            // Iterate through directories and add all filtered files.
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            foreach (string filter in options.FileTypes) {
                foreach (string dir in directories) {
                    LoadFilesInternal(dir, filter, options, ref files);
                }
            }
            return files.ToArray();
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Adds all directories within the root directory 
        /// to an existing array of directories.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="root">The root directory.</param>
        /// <param name="directories">The array to add the new directories.</param>
        /// <param name="recursive">TRUE to get all sub-directories recursivly.</param>
        public static void AddDirectory(string root, ref string[] directories, bool recursive = false)
        {            
            if (!(directories.Contains(root)) && !(recursive)) {
                string[] dirNew = new string[directories.Length + 1];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(directories, 0, dirNew, 0, directories.Length);
                dirNew[dirNew.Length - 1] = root;
                directories = dirNew;
                dirNew = new string[0];
                dirNew = null;
            }
            else if (!(directories.Contains(root)) && recursive) {
                List<string> dirTemp = new List<string>();
                dirTemp.AddRange(directories);
                GetDirectoriesRecursInternal(root, ref dirTemp);
                directories = dirTemp.ToArray();
            }
        }


        //
        // Gets all the directories and sub-directories 
        // in the specified root directory.
        //
        private static void GetDirectoriesRecursInternal(string dir, ref List<string> directories)
        {
            // Get standard set of information.
            FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS findLevel = FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoStandard;
            // File name search.
            FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS findOps = FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS.FindExSearchNameMatch;

            int additionalFlags = 0;
            // Check if OS version is later supported
            // OS beginning from WinSvr 2008 R2 and Win 7.
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
                // Ignore short file name to improve performance.
                findLevel = FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoBasic;
                // Use larger buffer.
                additionalFlags = FIND_FRIST_EX_LARGE_FETCH;
            }

            // Format path to match FindFirstFileExW pattern.
            dir = FormatPath(dir);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir)) {
                return;
            }

            WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
            // Try to get handle to first file system object.
            IntPtr hFind = FindFirstFileExW(
                dir, findLevel,
                out ffd, findOps,
                IntPtr.Zero, additionalFlags
            );

            // FindFirstFileExW failed...
            if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) {
                int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                _errors.Add("FindFirstFileExW returned Win32 error: " + err);
                return;
            }

            // Stores end of directory name without search pattern.
            // Used to create new directory name.
            string end = string.Empty;
            // Stores the new concatinated directory name.
            string newDir = string.Empty;

            do
            {
                // Check if handle points to directory.
                if ((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) 
                    == FileAttributes.Directory)
                {
                    // Ignore if handle points to current directory
                    // or top-level directory.
                    if (ffd.cFileName != ".." && ffd.cFileName != ".") {
                        // Remove wildcard from current directory.
                        end = dir.Replace("\\*", string.Empty);
                        // Create new directory name.
                        newDir = end + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ffd.cFileName;
                        directories.Add(newDir);
                        GetDirectoriesRecursInternal(newDir, ref directories);
                    }
                }
            } while (FindNextFile(hFind, out ffd));
        }


        //
        // Gets all the directories in the specified root directory.
        //
        private static void GetDirectoriesInternal(string root, ref List<string> directories)
        {
            // Get standard set of information.
            FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS findLevel = FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoStandard;
            // File name search.
            FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS findOps = FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS.FindExSearchNameMatch;

            int additionalFlags = 0;
            // Check if OS version is later supported
            // OS beginning from WinSvr 2008 R2 and Win 7.
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
                // Ignore short file name to improve performance.
                findLevel = FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoBasic;
                // Use larger buffer.
                additionalFlags = FIND_FRIST_EX_LARGE_FETCH;
            }

            // Format path to match FindFirstFileExW pattern.
            root = FormatPath(root);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(root)) {
                return;
            }

            WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
            // Try to get handle to first file system object.
            IntPtr hFind = FindFirstFileExW(
                root, findLevel,
                out ffd, findOps,
                IntPtr.Zero, additionalFlags
            );

            // FindFirstFileExW failed... 
            if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) {
                int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                _errors.Add("FindFirstFileExW returned Win32 error: " + err);
                return;
            }

            // Stores end of directory name without search pattern.
            // Used to create new directory name.
            string end = string.Empty;
            // Stores the new concatinated directory name.
            string newDir = string.Empty;

            do
            {
                // Check if handle points to a directory.
                if ((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) 
                    == FileAttributes.Directory)
                {
                    // Ingore if handle points to current directory
                    // or top-level directory.
                    if (ffd.cFileName != ".." && ffd.cFileName != ".") {
                        // Remove wildcard from current directory.
                        end = root.Replace("\\*", string.Empty);
                        // Create new directory name.
                        newDir = end + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ffd.cFileName;
                        directories.Add(newDir);
                    }
                }
            } while (FindNextFile(hFind, out ffd));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all directories from the root directory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="root">The root directory.</param>
        /// <param name="recurse">TRUE to get all sub-directories recursivly.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string[] GetDirectories(string root, bool recurse = true)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            if (recurse) {
                // Get all sub-directories.
                GetDirectoriesRecursInternal(root, ref list);
            }
            else {
                // Top-level directories only.
                GetDirectoriesInternal(root, ref list);
            }
            return list.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```